# Findbugs exclude generated files

Tags: maven, ant, findbugs

I am trying to filter out the generated files from the findbugs check and all I tried does not seem to work.
Pretty much part of my build process I create a whole lot of classes that end up in a folder called src/generated
I would be interested in filtering out all those classes.
I am using maven but I don't think it matters.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what you tried it's a bit problematic to help.

Here's a fragment we use to skip over a few bug patterns present in code generated by Avro.

```xml
<FindBugsFilter>
  <Match>
    <!-- Avro generates redundant "implements" interface declarations -->
    <Or>
      <Package name="~com[.]foo[.]plugh[.]avro([.].*)?"     />
      <Package name="~com[.]foo[.]xyzzy[.]protocol([.].*)?" />
    </Or>

    <Or>
      <Bug pattern="RI_REDUNDANT_INTERFACES" />
      <Bug pattern="NM_CLASS_NAMING_CONVENTION" />
      <Bug pattern="REC_CATCH_EXCEPTION" />
    </Or>
  </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

Comment: Thanks Dave,


I have the src/main/java source folder that I am OK to check for bugs.


I also have src/generated/java source folder that is generated during the build. I want to exclude generated code from bugs checks because being generated it is outside my control.


Hope this clarifies what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Julian I know what you're trying to do, I don't know what you've tried. The above skips the defined bugs for the defined packages.

Comment: I can't locate the classes to exclude based on the package names but I can locate them based on the folder they sit in. That is pretty much my main problem.

Comment: This worked also on a multi module project for me, thx. I just placed the findbugs-exclude.xml file in the same folder containing the parent pom.xml.

Comment: I tried placing the findbugs-exclude.xml file in the same directory as parent pom, but it didn't work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how using the Codehaus findbugs-maven-plugin.  You include the packages you DO want to analyze, instead of excluding those you don't.

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <onlyAnalyze>com.company.util.*,com.company.myapp.*</onlyAnalyze>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: This will still find bugs in generated classes, as they are generated in the same packages.

Comment: Possible, yes. Some code generation plugins allow specification of the package name. I have an app using cxf-xjc-plugin that does exactly that. Change the package name and it becomes easy to ignore the classes. This may not be an option depending on the tool used.